# How to make fluffy rice and which type of type of rice to use?

Tags: rice

In some restaurants like Greek ones I get some nice pretty fluffy rice. The rice is short and little fat in the middle. It doesn't like look Jasmine or basmati rice which are longer.

When I prepare rice at home I follow the instructions in terms of amount of water, rice and simmering at lowest heat. Still the rice comes out pretty sticky. (Another question here talks about adding water in batches.. will try).

Question: How can I make the fluffiest rice and what type of rice to use? Do rice cookers make fluffier rice than using a pot?

Answer (score 4):

As is mentioned in [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/772/why-do-you-have-to-rinse-rice) (and [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12651/should-rice-be-washed-with-hot-water-or-cold-water)), one of the keys to keeping your rice from clumping is to rinse the uncooked rice with cold water until the water runs clear. This rinses off the starch on the surface of the rice. The starch can cause your rice to stick together.

Some types of rice are fluffier than others. The longer grain rices tend to have lower starch (and, of course, [Arborio](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/781/arborio-and-risotto) rice has so much starch that it makes for the characteristic texture of risotto). So even if it's not Jasmine or Basmati, they're probably using at least a medium grain, rather than short.

A quick Google search for Greek rice yields a lot of recipes that suggest sauteing the rice in oil before boiling it. This is a common technique for pilaf, and adds a nutty sort of taste. I'm not sure it'd have any effect on stickiness, but it might help with flavor. And you can also saute onions and other vegetables to add flavor.

Comment: +1 Nice answer but i disagree with the note about sauteing the rice. The sauteing will actually crack the grain thus allowing the starch inside to leak out and cause for more clumping rather than less. Though the process does make for a nicer pilaf.